# What is the supremum of this set?

Tags: real-analysis

[Wikipedia on Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29)

So X = {0; 0,1; 0,12; 0,123; 0,1234; ...}

**I know that the infimum is zero**. But what is the supremum of this set? The elements of the set is ex: 0; 0,1; 0,12; 0,123; 0,1234; 0,12345; 0,123456; 0,1234567; 0,12345678; 0,12345679; 0,12345678910; 0,1234567891011; ...etc..

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'what is'? What kind of description of that number are you hoping to get?

Comment: Do the digits reach $9$ and then repeat starting with $0$, or repeat starting with $1$, or do you starting writing two digit numbers after the first $9$, e.g. $0.1234567891011$?

Comment: two digits! ...

Comment: It's very irritating to get "-1" without any comments that what is the problem with my question :\

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting that the supremum is a transcendental real number, hence why some of the answers suggest that there is no "nice" way of writing it down.

Answer (score 3):

The number that is the supremum (and in particular the *limit*) of this sequence, is known as the [Champernowne constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant). It has some interesting properties.

There is, however, not a "nice" way of writing this number down; at least, not "nicer" than the suggestive $0.1234567891011\ldots$

Comment: I have to admit that when I looked at the discussion of the continued fraction of the Champernowne constant in the WP article, I laughed for about 2 minutes straight. Maybe I have a peculiar sense of humor. :-P

Comment: I laughed too. Use that 19th convergent as a pin!

Answer (score 0):

If you keep adding new extra digits to get from one number to the next then your numbers keep increasing, and the supremum will be the number you get when you keep writing digits forever using the pattern without stopping. In your case, the digits will not have any repeating subsequence so the supremum is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

The supremum of the simpler set $\{0,0.1,0.11,0.111,0.1111,\ldots\}$ is $0.1111\ldots$, which in this case we can simplify to $\frac19$.

Similarly, the supremum of your set is the number whose decimal expansion is $0.1234567891011\ldots$; but in this case there is no simpler expression.